# sort command to sort certain lines that start with a specific word

Tags: bash

I want to sort a file based on the second column but I also want to sort only the lines that start with the word "@SQ", meaning that the lines that have not been sorted have to stay in the same position as they first were.

`sort -k 2,2 filename`

input:

```
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:chr11 LN:197195432
@SQ     SN:chr8 LN:181748087
@SQ     SN:chr6 LN:181741298
@SQ     SN:chr5 LN:111089233
@PL     ID:Me   RF:091284293
```

Desired output:

```
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:chr5 LN:111089233
@SQ     SN:chr6 LN:181741298
@SQ     SN:chr8 LN:181748087
@SQ     SN:chr11 LN:197195432
@PL     ID:Me   RF:091284293
```

Comment: show the input example and desired result

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: that was a careless mistake, sorry about that. I have updated my question I only want to sort lines that start with the word @SQ

Comment: It's not clear from your input/output examples, but would it be fair to assume that you want to sort the @SQ lines **naturally**, not ascii? That is, ignore SN:chr and sort numerically?

Comment: could be there multiple sections with non-`@SQ` and `@SQ` lines (intermediate fragments)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes for non-@SQ sections. However there will be only one SQ section

Comment: How big a file do you expect to process ? (number of lines that is). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter roughly 100 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you need to do by reading from two different *file descriptors* and substituting the sorted lines for the unsorted lines in your final output. Essentially you can isolate and sort lines beginning with `'@SQ'` by utilizing the *version* sort capability of `sort -V`, e.g.

```
grep '^@SQ' <filename.txt | sort -V
```

You can then read the original file line-by-line by reading through a second file descriptor allowing you to read the output of the sorted lines above on `stdin`, e.g. below reading on FD 3,

```
while read -r line <&3; do 
    ...
        read -r sorted
    ...
done 3<"filename.txt"
```

(note if your version of `read` doesn't provide the `-r` option, just eliminate it)

Putting those two pieces together, you can do:

```
grep '^@SQ' <filename.txt | sort -V |
while read -r line <&3; do 
    if [ "${line%% *}" = '@SQ' ]; then  ## line begins with '@SQ'
        read -r sorted
        echo "$sorted"
    else 
        echo "$line"
    fi
done 3<"filename.txt"
```

Where I stored your unsorted file in `dat/sortdata.txt`. You can get the output you desire with:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ grep '^@SQ' <dat/sortdata.txt | sort -V |
> while read -r line <&3; do
>     if [ "${line%% *}" = '@SQ' ]; then  ## line begins with '@SQ'
>         read -r sorted
>         echo "$sorted"
>     else
>         echo "$line"
>     fi
> done 3<"dat/sortdata.txt"
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:chr5 LN:111089233
@SQ     SN:chr6 LN:181741298
@SQ     SN:chr8 LN:181748087
@SQ     SN:chr11 LN:197195432
@PL     ID:Me   RF:091284293
```

You could redirect the output to a separate file if you like by executing the above in a subshell and redirecting the output to a file. Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning python, so I won't claim that this is pretty or efficient, but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from natsort import natsorted
import re

insq = False
sq = []
r = re.compile( r"^@SQ")
with open( "franchini", "r" ) as f:
  for line in f:
    if not r.match( line ):
      if insq:
        for i in  natsorted(sq):
          print(i)
      print( line.strip() )
      insq = False
    else:
      sq.append( line.strip() )
      insq = True
```

This saved as fran.py and your sample data in franchini gives the following result:

```
./fran.py
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:chr5 LN:111089233
@SQ     SN:chr6 LN:181741298
@SQ     SN:chr8 LN:181748087
@SQ     SN:chr11 LN:197195432
@PL     ID:Me   RF:091284293
```

Answer (score 0):

***Python*** solution:

***sort_sq_lines.py*** script:

```
import re, sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    sq_lines = []
    for l in lines:
        if l.startswith('@SQ'):
            sq_lines.append(l)
        else:
            if sq_lines:
                processed = sorted(sq_lines, key=lambda l: int(re.split(r'(\s+)', l)[2][6:]))
                print('\n'.join(i for i in processed))
            print(l)
```

Usage:

```
python sort_sq_lines.py filename
```

The output:

```
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:chr5 LN:111089233
@SQ     SN:chr6 LN:181741298
@SQ     SN:chr8 LN:181748087
@SQ     SN:chr11 LN:197195432
@PL     ID:Me   RF:091284293
```